# 3D scatter plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, scatter3d

Working in Julia and using `Plots`, I have an array of points that lie on two distinct surfaces.  The points are mixed together such that doing a surface plot looks like garbage, because it tries to connect points on the two surfaces.  I think the best way to get around this is to plot the points simply as dots in space.

> How do I plot points in 3D without connecting them by a surface?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  Does this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38848173/1409374) help?

Answer (score 6):

You can use scatter from Plots.

Just pass the coordinates of points as 3 arrays to scatter function

```
X = [x1, x2, x3]
Y = [y1, y2, y3]
Z = [z1, z2, z3]

scatter(X, Y, Z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Plots:

```
plt3d= Plots.plot(points[1,:],points[2,:], points[3,:],
     seriestype=:scatter, markersize = 7)
display(plt3d)
```

In the above, I assume the points are in a `3x<num_of_points>` array.
Also increased the marker size, as the 3d plots default is small.

Answer (score 2):

For an interactive plot, you can use PlotlyJS:

```
using PlotlyJS, CSV, DataFrames
df = dataset(DataFrame, "iris")
plot(
    df,
    x=:sepal_length, y=:sepal_width, z=:petal_width, color=:species,
    type="scatter3d", mode="markers"
)
```

source: https://plotly.com/julia/3d-scatter-plots/